# Calling a php variable in JS does not work

Tags: javascript, php

I’m trying to make a user input by reading the contents of my server directory with php. So the user can select a file, in my case a CSV file which gets saved into a variable and then gets processed further down in my JavaScript code that should make a chart from it. All it does now is output the path string of the selected file. I tried using the json_encode function but it still doesn’t seem to work.

```
<?php
$dir = '/var/www/html/';
$graphen = '';
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
 if ($dp = opendir($dir)) { 
 $files = array(); 
 while (($file = readdir($dp)) !== false) { 
  if (!is_dir($dir . $file)) { 
  $files[] = $file; 
  } 
 } 
 closedir($dp); 
 } else { 
 exit('Directory not opened.'); 
 } 
 if ($files) { 
 echo '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="post">'; 
 foreach ($files as $file) { 
  echo '<input type="checkbox" name="files[]" value="' . $file . '" /> ' . 
   $file . '<br />'; 
 } 
 echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />' . 
  '</form>'; 
 } else { 
 exit('No files found.'); 
 } 
} else { 
 if (isset($_POST['files'])) { 
 foreach ($_POST['files'] as $value) {
  $graphen .= $dir . $value . '<br />';
 } 
 } else { 
 exit('No files selected'); 
 }
} 
echo $graphen;
?>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en">

<head>
    
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

   
    <script src="highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="data.js"></script>
    <script src="exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="export-data.js"></script>
    <script src="accessibility.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <div id="container1"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var fileName = <?php echo json_encode($graphen); ?>; //doesn't work
       

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: fileName,
                success: function (data) {
                    drawChart(data)
                }
            });


        function drawChart(raw_data) {
          //my code to draw chart is here and working
}
```

Comment: You should read the contents of the file instead of assigning the path to the variable. Also decode the assigned JSON in fileName using JS parse to convert that to JS objects. And also you can't read the files in the server using JS. So read the contents using PHP and assign that to js variable and decode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign a String to a variable in JavaScript, use `"` or `'`:

`var x = "Hello";`

Your current code results in

`var fileName = <?php echo json_encode($graphen); ?>;` => `var fileName = variable;`

Add quotes and it should work:

`var fileName = '<?php echo json_encode($graphen); ?>';` => `var fileName = 'variable';`